# Number of windings keeping constant the poles

Tags: motor, generator, winding

What happens if I increase the number of windings around the poles keeping constant the number of poles in a motor? for sure the rotational speed should be the same, I think that we will obtain a more stable working point thanks to a higher magnetic flux physically speaking, but I'm not sure. Do you know what is the consequence?

Comment: What does this mean: *a more stable working point*? Are we talking DC or AC motors, brushed or un-brushed? Why has this got anything to do with generators? If it's a DC motor, the speed will reduce.

Comment: What sort of motor?

Comment: @RoyC I wanted to make a simple motor with some objects that can be found at home. I have seen a video on youtube where one person makes this realization. it is a DC motor with a battery of 20 volt more or less. I want to understand how many meters of copper cable I should buy, but before I need to understand what change if I add a certain number of windings.

Comment: @Andyaka I wanted to make a simple motor with some objects that can be found at home. I have seen a video on youtube where one person makes this realization. it is a DC motor with a battery of 20 volt more or less. I want to understand how many meters of copper cable I should buy, but before I need to understand what change if I add a certain number of windings.

Comment: @SamueleBenitodiGioia I'd buy copper wire on the size of the rolls, but I suppose it is useful to know whether you'll need 20 metres or 200. (If the wire comes on 50m rolls, and I need 20m of wire, I'd probably buy a whole 50m roll. then if I screw it up I can try again)

Comment: @user253751 thank you for your advice!

Comment: (plus the extra 30m of wire will be useful for something else later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an AC induction or synchronous motor the speed will be the same the torque will be higher.

For a DC motor speed =
\$V_s -R_a I_a \over k \Phi \$
so as flux increases speed will decrease, torque however will increase.

If you are going to make a small demonstration type of DC motor you are going to get more benefit by making your armature with two coils at right angles. This will give you a motor which runs more reliably and stably. This means your commutator has to have four segments (or pieces of wire).

Comment: "so as flux increases speed will decrease, torque however will increase" , why flux increases if we increase number of field  winding , isn't flux in core should be constant as $$\phi =NI/Reluctance $$ and N is inversely proportional to I?

Comment: @user215805 it's true that N is inversely proportional to I but the current decreases a bit because the only losses are the cable ones, so N increases a lot with respect to the decrease of I, this is why the flux increase

Comment: @royC Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### DC motor

The reason why a DC motor settles at a given constant speed is because the back emf produced (due to rotation) increases as speed increases. At some point, as the motor is accelerating up in speed from a standing start, the back emf (increasing with speed) and applied voltage (constant) reach a point where they are nearly the same. This means that the current into the motor is at just the right amount to counter the mechanical effects of load and losses.

When the speed hasn't reached the final target speed, the back emf is less and this causes an excess of current to flow and, that excess of current produces sufficient extra torque to accelerate the motor to a higher speed. Eventually, the motor reaches a point where the current has reduced to a value that is just enough to sustain a constant speed given the mechanical load and losses.

More turns means a bigger back emf for a given speed and this naturally means that the motor runs at a slower speed once equilibrium has been reached.

> *for sure the rotational speed should be the same*

Incorrect.

Comment: thank you very much, it's clear now!